# How to tell outlook to not to keep trying to send receive

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

How do I tell outlook 2013 to not to send receive emails **FOR A SPECIFIC GMAIL IMAP ACCOUNT ?**. I want all other accounts to work normally...

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the send & receive groups.

File > Options > Advance > Send & Receive

Now you would see the different accounts - You need to untick "Include the selected account in this group" for your GMAIL account.

Comment: I did that. but after I click on inbox, it again tries to synchronize.

Comment: That option is for automatically sending & receiving for all checkmarked accounts.  Unless you want it to never fetch your mail for this account (which seems to defeat the purpose of having the account set up at all) you have to let it sync the first time, but then it won't try sending/receiving automatically when it updates the other accounts.

Comment: I remember a user used to complain in the past due to the sync errors, so I followed the steps on this link, being the resolution - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/230aff21-35ad-4959-8b49-0cb3b0697506/how-do-i-turn-off-logging-in-sync-issues-folder-in-outlook-2007?forum=outlook